# How to list all called methods?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way that I can list all called methods like there are called one after the other? For example now I am doing same thing in way that I'm putting NSLog(@"MethodName"); i every that method. 
I want to do that by automatic way in NSLog. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app

Comment: Not helped. App stops...

Comment: It works, jsut read carefully. :)

Comment: It supposed you confuse "Condition" field in breakpoint popover with "Action" field. Paste this code `expr -- (void)printf("[%s, %s]\n",(char *) object_getClassName(*(long*)($esp+4)), (char *) *(long *)($esp+8) )` in "Action->Debugger Command" field. It works, I've checked.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too much methods you can use

```
NSLog(@"%@" , NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

to log their names. This way you don't have to copy the signatures manually each time.

Comment: I believe
    `NSLog(@"%s", __func__);`

will be better in this case 'cause it logs class's name too.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property 'NSMutableArray *calledMethods;`

And in each of your method use

`[self.calledMethods addObject:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]`;

And whenever you want to print it NSLog it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ) ;
```

Which produces (for example)

> -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]

Or, you can use dtrace. This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874726/210171.

Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604249/210171 (same linked question). Seems there's an environment variable `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` you can set...